# Bugshooting for Redmine

Tags: fogbugz, redmine

Is there any bug shooting utility submitting directly into Redmine? Something like bugshooting.com is doing with FogBugz.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Usersnap for Redmine](https://usersnap.com/redmine) is exactly what you need.

Add Usersnap to your web project and [connect Usersnap with Redmine](https://usersnap.com/doc/connect/redmine) - you will get bug screenshots directly added to your Redmine tickets as attachment.

Full disclosure: I'm CTO and Co-Founder of [Usersnap](https://usersnap.com).

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found anything directly (we use Bug Shooting as well with BugTracker.net).

One easy workaround would be to enable email to issue in Redmine, so you can email new issues to your Redmine instance.

Then, you can use Bug Shooting, but you should create a new 'server' for the new email type. This just creates a new email message for you with the screen shot attached.

When you email this to your Redmine instance, it should take the screenshot and add it as an attachment to the new issue created.